# Converting a string to an expression in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I'm writing a small MATLAB package and I'd like to ask for user input for a function. So if the user enters:

```
x.^2 + sin(x)
```

I want to use this user input to appear elsewhere in the code, but `x` would already be defined and so the expression above would be a vector (or scalar if `length(x)` is 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function for this. For example:

```
>> x = 5

x =

     5

>> eval('x*3')

ans =

    15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function handle:

```
% some variable you already defined
myVar = 5;

% Create an anonymous function in some z 
f = str2func('@(z) z.^2 + sin(z)');

% Call function supplying the input
f(myVar)
```